# reassigning javascript objects

Tags: javascript, object, pass-by-reference

If javascript objects are assign by reference, shouldn't the second console.log show that obj2 = {c:3}

```
let obj1 = {a:1}
let obj2 = {b:2}

obj2 = obj1
console.log(obj2) // {a:1}

obj1 = {c:3}
console.log(obj2)  // still {a:1}
```

Comment: No, changing what `obj1` points to doesn't magically change what `obj2` points to, and the last edit to `obj2` made it point to the same thing as `obj1` at the time of the assignment, which was `{ a: 1 }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first you have this (both references pointing to the same object):

```
obj1 => {a:1} <= obj2
```

When you do `obj1 = {c:3}`, you do 2 things:

- sever the connection `obj1 =x=> {a:1}`
- create a new connection `obj1 => {c:3}`

Note that obj2 is unchanged (still pointing to the same thing): `obj2 => {a:1}`

So `console.log(obj2)` SHOULD still be = `{a:1}`

Answer (score 0):

In short, variables references changed, but not memory address:

[image]

Comment: so how we make change obj1 in this case?

Comment: `obj1` has changed by reassign: `obj1 = {c:3}`.

Comment: oh yeah I mistaken in reading the code. I thought the last one is ojb1 is written in console